# Broader Sanctions

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning, ambiguity

In this [article](http://www.latimes.com/world/europe/la-fg-wn-obama-merkel-ukraine-spying-news-conference-20140502,0,5373595.story#axzz30hbhulCh)

> President Obama and German Chancellor Angela Merkel on Friday ratcheted up the threat of economic backlash against Russia, saying they are preparing ***broader sanctions*** if Moscow continues to stoke violence in eastern Ukraine in the run-up to elections later this month.

Would "a broader range of sanctions" be better than "broader sanctions", because in the latter, "broader" appears to apply to each individual sanction (a broader sanction), not the combined entirety of the sanctions?

Answer (score 1):

While "sanctions" implies a range of measures being the plural of sanction, broader does not necessarily apply to the range measures.  Broader could be interpreted as an adjective on the sanctions, meaning that additional sanctions may be designed to individually have more impact. Each individual sanction is not necessarily equal.

Comment: So, "broader sanctions" = "more sanctions"?

Comment: That depends on what you mean by "more". More could mean that there are individually more sanctions.  It could also mean that each individual sanction has more impact.  The definition of "sanction" includes "...a penalty for disobeying a rule or law...".  Penalties can vary depending on what rule or law has been broken.  "Broader" could mean more small penalties and it could mean that the penalties will be more severe. It has an open ended meaning.

Answer (score 0):

IMO **broader sanctions** is an expression vivid enough to convey both President Obama’s and Chancellor Angela Merkel’s meaning. They both know exactly what they are dealing with.

If you use **broader range of sanctions** this doesn’t imply that you add anything supplementary, that is that the sanctions would be larger or some of the kind, which may change the implication of the message conveyed.

Comment: So, "broader sanctions" = "more sanctions"?

Comment: broader = wider = larger = greater =more (in this context)